# After upgrading the android Target Version app no longer compiles

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After upping the android target version I had to update a bunch of NUGET packages.  Now After upgrading a bunch of things during troubleshooting, I can't get past this list of errors:

```
1>D:\...\project.Android\obj\Debug\121\lp\176\jl\res\values\values.xml(1482): error APT1000: Attribute "android:translationX" has already been defined
1>D:\...\project.Android\obj\Debug\121\lp\176\jl\res\values\values.xml(1486): error APT1000: Attribute "android:translationY" has already been defined
1>D:\...\project.Android\obj\Debug\121\lp\176\jl\res\values\values.xml(1489): error APT1000: Attribute "android:translationZ" has already been defined
1>D:\...\project.Android\obj\Debug\121\lp\156\jl\res\values\values.xml(5): error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected
1>D:\...\project.Android\obj\Debug\121\lp\151\jl\res\values\values.xml(4): error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected
1>D:\...\project.Android\obj\Debug\121\lp\149\jl\res\values\values.xml(4): error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected
1>D:\...\project.Android\obj\Debug\121\lp\144\jl\res\values\values.xml(4): error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected
```

These are all generated files, so I'm not sure where to go from here.  Some searching showed making sure all projects Xam-Forms version matched, which they do.  I also tried the normal close VS, delete bin&obj in project, clean and compile.  At a loss any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also delete hidden .vs folder. If still bad, IIRC, there is a way to delete all cached nuget packages, and force them to redownload. If still bad, it might be worth creating a new empty xamarin.forms project. Don't put your code there yet, just start adding nugets to it, until you get one of these errors. Try to identify which combination of nugets is causing problem.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I was able to remove those errors after going through all the nuget packages and manually verifying all the versions matched up with the requirements and all required dependencies where installed.  Then everything worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove those errors after going through all the nuget packages and manually verifying all the versions matched up with the requirements and all required dependencies where installed. Then everything worked.